# Continuous on Disconnected Domain

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Lets say we have a function f(x): which has domain only of [1,3] and [5,7]. Further, the function f(x) is Continuous over the respective intervals.

Now, as the function is continuous over the respective intervals and considering that points (3,5) are not in the domain, Can we say the whole function is continuous?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/290189) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).

Comment: What do you think? Continuity is only defined with respect to some domain...

Comment: I think if we think like this, then even F(x) = 1/x will also continuous over R - {0}. But, generally it doesn't seem like that.

Comment: http://math.mit.edu/~jspeck/18.01_Fall%202014/Supplementary%20notes/01c.pdf Please look at Example 5 in this. The author says F(x)= 1/x has one point of discontinuity and the discontinuity is infinte there.

Comment: $F(x) = 1/x$ is continuous in $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ and *undefined* at $x = 0$. But if you *define* $F(0) =$ anything, $F$ will be discontinuous at $x = 0$.

Comment: Oh okay. Got it. So the discontinuity is infinite there basically means if we take the domain to be R for f(x) = 1/x and take f(x) to be anything at x=0 still we cant remove the discontinuity. Am I correct in stating that?

Comment: @GadinNaidu, correct.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Really appreciate it :)